# Conjugation action on a semi-direct product $N\rtimes H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, group-homomorphism, sylow-theory

> Let $G$ be a  finite group, with $H\le G$ and $N\trianglelefteq G$ such that $G=N\rtimes H$.
> Suppose that the conjugation action of $H$ on $N$ induces $2$ orbits in $N$. Prove the following requests:
> a) $\exists p$ prime  $\forall 1\ne n\in N$ such that $o(n)=p.$ 
> b) SHow that $N$ is abelian.

I said that if $G=N\rtimes H$, hence we have the conditions $(*)\begin{cases}N \cap H=\{1_G\}\\NH=G \end{cases}$. For a generic element, $n \in N$ the stabilizer of $n$ in the action $\varphi:H\to\operatorname{Aut}(N)$ is such that $h^{-1}nh=n\iff h\in C_H(n)$, whose order divides $H$.
Furthermore, if the number of orbits is two, the quotient $H/Ker(\varphi)\cong \varphi(H)\le\operatorname{Aut}(N)$ has order two, with $Ker(\varphi):=\underset{n\in N}\bigcap C_H(n)$. I'm confusing things because the map induced by the semi-direct product has the same form of the map induced by the conjugation action and I'm not sure about how using the Hypothesis $(*)$.
If $N$ is abelian it means that its centralizer is the entire $G$ (with $C_G(H)\le Z(G)$), and in particular, considering tha action restricted to $H$, $C_H(N)$ should corespond to $H$.

Thank for the help and for your patience.

Comment: I think that your quantifiers are not correct. It's not "for all $n\not=1$ there exists $p$" but rather "there exists $p$ such that for all $n\not=1$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under conjugation one orbit is just the identity. So all other elements of $N$ are conjugate in $G$ and therefore have the same order.

Let this order be a multiple of the prime $p$, then the $p$th power of an element of $N$ is still in $N$ but has a smaller order i.e. it has to be the identity.

Since $N$ is a $p$-group, $Z(N)$ is non-trivial and is a characteristic subgroup of $N$. Therefore $Z(N)$ is fixed by $H$ and so all elements of $N$ are in $Z(N)$.

Comment: The Kernel of the map is in $H$ and so has no intersection with $Z(N)$ which is the subgroup of interest.

Comment: Sorry, the last thing. Did you state that N is a p group for Sylow's theorem?

Comment: Yes, you could use Sylow. But it's simpler than that really. By Cauchy's Theorem if a prime divides the order of the group then it has an element of order that prime. Therefore a finite group with all elements of order a power of a prime p must be a p-group.

Comment: I think that $\nexists $ a non trivial subgroup $L \trianglelefteq G$ contained in $N$... This should be true (?)

Comment: That is correct. Such a subgroup $L$ would be fixed by the action of $H$ and we know this cannot be the case because of the number of orbits.

Comment: Thank you so much. Being honest I hardly understood the part where you show that $N$ is a p-group. You supposed that the order of the non trivial elements (the elements in the second orbit) has order a multiple of a prime $p$. Then you wrote that the p-th power of a generic non trivial element in $N$ is $n^p$, which is still in $N$ but its order will be a number $m<p$ hence it has to be the identity. I'm not understanding the last implication (modulo this was what you meant).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118523/discussion-between-vajra-and-s-dolan).